# How to create .apk from C++ code with Cocos2Dx

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I would like to work with the framework Cocos2D-x. I have installed everything and started a new project. I added C++ code into the proj.win32, and it works smoothly.

I picked this framework because i want to do an app for Android, but i have a few questions :

- Is it possible to do Android apps in C++ with Cocos ?
- How do I generate an .apk from C++ code ?

I would like to have a .apk that can be used by an emulator like bluestacks for instance.

Does someone know of a way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: please read this document http://www.cocos2d-x.org/programmersguide/I/index.html
Also remember this framework is focus on games, if you want to work on android maybe you should use eclipse of Android studio to work.

Comment: @Hammerh5 What about games for Android ?

Comment: Yes you can if you create games in Win32 android should work fine. compile with cocos console "compile -p android" then go to the "proj.android/bin/yourGame.apk" and run with your android device

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend writing applications using a 2D game engine. There will be a lot of things you would have to do just to get basic application type behavior from it. The android libraries is more than enough to make any application. If you are looking for a cross platform application development framework use something like [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/) or [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). But to answer your question you can use

```
cocos run -p android -j 4
```

To run the application. It will produce a apk file in the debug folder it displays in the console. Or you can run the build_native.py file in the android project to produce the APK. The script can be run in Debug or Release, you need to have python installed to execute the script.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal, just go to your project directory and write the following command:

> cocos run -p android

It will create an apk inside ~YourProjectDirectory/bin/debug/android/YourGame-debug.apk

Comment: Thanks for the command line. I got an error however. 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 25698 : character   maps to <undefined>